# Why can't class be destructed in polymorphism C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the problem with using the polymorphism.
The code here:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {cout << "construct a" << endl;}
    virtual ~A() {cout << "destroy a" << endl;}
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B() {cout << "construct b" << endl;}
    ~B() {cout << "destroy b" << endl;}
};
void main() {
    A *p = new B;
}
```

The result is:

```
construct a
construct b
```

Why 'p' can not be destroyed or may i be wrong somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: because you leak memory: you're missing `delete p;` at the end of `main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke

```
delete p;
```

to delete the pointer and call the destructor. Dynamically allocated objects do not have their destructor called automatically, that's why you need to invoke the `delete` operator, which first invokes the destructor then calls `operator delete`  to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are allocating data with the `new` operator. If you want to have the destructors invoked make sure to delete the pointer with

```
delete p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare `p` as `std::unqiue_ptr<A> p(new B);` - the unique pointer will delete the pointer at the end of scope.

Answer (score 0):

By using ordinary pointers, you've said you want to manage the lifetime of your object yourself. Since you never said to destroy the object (`delete p;` will do that, so long as `p` is pointing to the object), it never got destroyed.

Normally, you should let the lifetime of your objects be managed automatically. The two basic tools are:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> p { new B };
```

With `unique_ptr`, only one pointer is allowed to "own" the object. When this pointer is gone, the object it points to will automatically be destroyed. The other tool is

```
std::shared_ptr<A> p { new B };
// or p = make_shared<B>();
```

Multiple shared pointers can "share" ownership of the object. When all of the shared pointers are gone, the object will be automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

A call to new allocates memory on the heap. You need to explicitly dealocate this memory using the `delete` operator. Doing otherwise causes dreaded memory leaks. Since this is a common source of errors,  you may be interested in using `std::unique_ptr` or  `boost::scoped_ptr`